# Installing GitEye om Mac 64 bit raises error

Tags: java, giteye

Git eye didn't install.

This is the error log.

```
!SESSION 2016-02-12 13:55:51.682 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_65
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=nl_NL
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -data @user.home/.giteye -keyring /Users/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin 
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefpane
```

Then install the latest java JDK  (not SDK!)